# Sum of power series $\sum_n((2x)^n)/n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

How do I find the sum of this power series?

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac1n(2x)^n$$

Differentiating the expression I get $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty (2x)^{n-1}$.

I assume that is supposed to be some clue, but I don’t see how. Any advice?

Comment: First you have to find the values of $x$ the power series converges.

Comment: When you differentiate you should get $2^nx^{n-1}$ instead. Multiplying by $x$ you get the sum of $2^nx^n=(2x)^n$, which is geometric. Remember that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}r^n=\frac{1}{1-r}$. Put in it $r=2x$. So, that means that if your series is $f(x)$, then $xf'(x)=\frac{1}{1-2x}$. To find $f$ you divide by $x$ and integrate.

Comment: @DiegoMath Convergence is only important if one intends to evaluate the series. It is not needed, and often doesn't help in finding the sum.

Comment: Thank you! I now see how it can be 1/1-2x. Problem is that the answer is supposed to be 2/1-2x. Is that due to the 2^n (n starting at 1)?

Comment: But when I divide 1/1-2x by x and integrate, I end up with a logarithmic expression?

Comment: Yes, the final answer involves a logarithm.